# I update a row in a repeater it will update correctly. when I refresh the page the previously updated row is populate again

Tags: ascx

I update a row in a repeater it will update correctly. what is my problem is when I refresh the page the previously updated row is populate again. How I stop that?

when i refresh a page the last updated row won't get populated